# How to set TTL Indexes in Mongodb document using mongo-go-driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go, mongo-go-driver

How do I set TTL indexes in a document using "mongo-go-driver"?

suppose here is my document model:

```
type Session struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    AccessToken  string             `json:"access_token" bson:"access_token"`
    ExpireOn     int64              `json:"expire_on" bson:"expire_on"`
}
```

and here I am inserting new document:

```
sessionCollection := database.Collection(COLLECTION_SESSION)

_, err = sessionCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), s)
if err != nil {
    responses.RespondWithERROR(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
    return
}
```

Now I want that this session will be removed after a few times.

I found the way to do that in documentation [Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) but can't figure out How to do the same thing in go using mongo-go-driver.

Comment: The time field must be of type time, not integer. Review driver documentation for how to insert times.

Comment: @D.SM I understand. Put it for another reason.